# Unit Testing Dynamic Query JPA Specification on Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I've some class to handle dynamic query like this below

```java
public class QueryFilter<T> implements Specification<T> {

    transient List<SearchCriteria> list;

    public QueryFilter() {
        this.list = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void add(SearchCriteria criteria) {
        list.add(criteria);
    }

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
        //create a new predicate list
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

        //add add criteria to predicates
        for (SearchCriteria criteria : list) {
            if (criteria.getOperation().equals(SearchOperation.EQUAL)) {
                predicates.add(builder.equal(root.get(criteria.getKey()), criteria.getValue1()));
            }  else if (criteria.getOperation().equals(SearchOperation.NOT_EQUAL)) {
                predicates.add(builder.notEqual(root.get(criteria.getKey()), criteria.getValue1()));
            } else if (criteria.getOperation().equals(SearchOperation.GREATER_THAN)) {
                predicates.add(builder.greaterThan(root.get(criteria.getKey()), criteria.getValue1().toString()));
            } else if (criteria.getOperation().equals(SearchOperation.LESS_THAN)) {
                predicates.add(builder.lessThan(root.get(criteria.getKey()), criteria.getValue1().toString()));
            } else if (criteria.getOperation().equals(SearchOperation.GREATER_THAN_EQUAL)) {
                predicates.add(builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get(criteria.getKey()), criteria.getValue1().toString()));
            } else if (criteria.getOperation().equals(SearchOperation.LESS_THAN_EQUAL)) {
                predicates.add(builder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get(criteria.getKey()), criteria.getValue1().toString()));
            } else if (criteria.getOperation().equals(SearchOperation.IN)) {
                predicates.add(builder.in(root.get(criteria.getKey())).value(criteria.getValue1()));
            } else if (criteria.getOperation().equals(SearchOperation.NOT_IN)) {
                predicates.add(builder.not(root.get(criteria.getKey())).in(criteria.getValue1()));
            }
        }
        return builder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    }
}
```

**Question :**
- how to create unit test for this class with junit 5?
- Note : my project using spring-boot

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and get your first badge.